# How to return a file as response along with custom response in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I am uploading the file of the student object and processing it.

An array of student JSON in a file. ( StudentList.txt)

```
[
{
 "id":"001",
 "name":"Jhon"
},
{
 "id":"002",
 "name":"Tom"
}
]
```

The response of the above request should be like below.

```
{
    "data" : {
              "success":"01",
              "failed":"01"
             },
   "message":"File upload has been done",
   "code":200,
   "path":"/student/file/upload"
}
```

along with a downloadable file with failed record information.
( If the second record failed during file upload the response file should be having the failed reason and failed record information in it.)

Answer (score 0):

The content type of your request should be in json format **application/json** and not a txt file.

To achieve what you want, I think you should do all your stuff in a service that is annotated with **@Transactional** and whenever an exception occurred a **global exception handler** will send a response containing the reason why the upload is failed

Comment: Let's say the file upload process has no error but some records are failed while inserting into DB. How to send error information of a particular record in a file in the same response?